# How to add an existing view with existing constraints into a scroll view (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I designed my view controller on my iPhone X.  When making it responsive to smaller phones, such as the iPhone 7/8 and SE, I need to put everything into a scroll view.  How can I keep the layout the same with all the constraints, but add a scroll functionality?

Comment: Embed all of your views into a scrollview constrained to the size of the view.

Comment: Why not place them in a scroll view for the iPhone X too?

Comment: I just meant that it fits nicely for iPhone X, when I add the scroll view, it will be for the X as well

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

1- drag a scrollView to the same hierarchy of the old View , give it leading , trailing , top , bottom constraints

2- copy that old view , paste it inside the scrollView give it leading , trailing , top , bottom constraints , and width constraint to the outer-most view

This graph may be simple , but if you follow it the scrollview should scroll

[image]

Comment: would I have to change any constraints on the objects in the existing view to the new scroll view?

Comment: if the objects inside that old view are placed well and have constraints from top to bottom the , then no need only the parent (which is the old view)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have done what you said, but when running on the simulator, the app crashed because the topmost that is anchored to the top of the view, not scroll view, has a nil value.  any suggestions?

Comment: with top-most view I mean outer view top in hierarchy which is self.view in code

Comment: UPDATE:  The everything is in the scroll view and nothing is not nil, but I am not able to scroll the elements in the scroll view.  Is there something im missing?  Ive done all this in storyboards, nothing programmatically .

Comment: can you screenshot the hierarchy and edit it in question

Comment: @DevilRunner anchor the top-most view to the top of the scroll view (or the content view, if you created one) and anchor the bottom-most view to the bottom of the scroll view (or the content view) and then it will scroll if all else is properly done.